What does "run" mean in "Yeah, they don't run Harvard at night, last time I checked."
In the movie "The Departed" there is a scene in which one of the police officers says that he is attending law school. When asked if it's "Suffolk, nights?" he responds.
"Yeah, they don't run Harvard at night, last time I checked."
Does "run" in this context mean...
c
: to direct the business or activities of: manage, conduct
run a factory(Merriam-Webster)
?
I think I might've heard "conduct classes at some people

"Conducting classes" is what places like Harvard actually do, so directing / managing those classes is the same as running them. But there's an element of facetious quirkiness in the phrasing of They don't run Harvard at night in the cited context, so you probably shouldn't copy it. Stick to more "normal" phrasing, like Harvard doesn't run night classes. You might well hear They don't run the factory on Sundays, but you're not likely to hear They don't run the school on Sundays

Suffolk University Law School in Boston is not prestigious like Harvard :Law School, which would never have night classes.

I. Meaning of the dialogue.

What does "run" mean in "Yeah, they don't run Harvard at night, last time I checked."

Here,  "run" means "offer" or "conduct".
The officer is comparing the law course in "Harvard University" and "Suffolk University Law School", which are both located in Boston.
So  the officer's remark can be interpreted as, "Yes, I did check at Harvard University. They don't offer night classes.
II. Understanding the scene in "The Departed"..
"Suffolk University" is well-known for its evening program, which is designed for working professionals. Many police officers and other working professionals in the Boston area attend Suffolk Law's evening program to earn their law degree while continuing to work full-time.
Considering this, the officer's remark is tongue in cheek.
What the officer actually meant was, "It's no big deal you have guessed correctly. It's a well known fact that Suffolk University and not Harvard University conducts night classes."

The meaning of "conduct" doesn't surprise me and this is what I was suspecting it means but "offer" is not a synonym of "run" AFAIK. Are you sure this is correct? Thanks anyway :)

@StaticBounce "offer" can  be understood in this context, especially in a more informal or conversational tone. "Offer" implies providing or making something available, which could include the idea of Harvard being "open for business" or operational at night.
So, all three options - "run", "conduct", and "offer" - can work in this sentence, depending on the tone and nuance you want to convey!

To run there is a colloquial synonym for conduct operations.

They don't run their boat rental business in the winter.

In the US, there are "night schools" that offer evening classes that cater to working people who are trying to get a degree in order to advance their career.  Back in the 1970s and 80s, elite institutions typically didn't offer such evening classes, though many of them now offer online degrees and some evening classes though these degrees are not granted by the core institution but by an affiliated college under the university aegis yet separate from the main undergraduate institution.
The verb run with this meaning is "street talk" with mercantilistic  connotations, and that contributes a sardonic humor to the statement.
